# Redis client: "Socket closed unexpectedly"

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, redis

What will be cause of this error from Redis client running on AWS lambda ?

**"message"**: "Socket closed unexpectedly"

**"stack"**: "Error: Socket closed unexpectedly\n    at Socket. (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/socket.js:195:118)\n    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:632:26)\n    at Socket.emit (node:events:517:28)\n    at TCP. (node:net:350:12)"

We are trying to read from Redis server from a Redis client running on nodejs18.x

Comment: Redis server is not running or accessible from Lambda function.